# How do I merge along a single axis?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a custom guitar pick. To create the curvature along the top of it, I created a series of edge loops and used proportional editing to pull the middle up.

Now, I'm aware that I can simply use the same loops to repeat the process at the tip, but as a beginner, I'm curious - is it possible to merge all the edges so the preserve the width of the pick along the y-axis, creating a single edge rather than averaging all the vertices along both the x and y resulting in a single point?

The picture below probably better conveys what I'm trying to ask. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: If you do what you want you'll get surface converging at perfectly thin angle which is not really existing. You could bevel it though afterwards, just try to avoid more than 5 edges sharing one vertex

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about doing this.

Method one is to merge the front edges first, then the back ones. If the vertices you are merging have no depth on a certain axis (the Y axis in your case) then merging them will not move them on that axis. Simply select the from ones, merge them, then the back, and merge them.

The second Method is to select all the vertices that you want to merge and scale them to 0 on whatever axis you want to merge the vertices along. In this case, you would press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> and finally <kbd>0</kbd> to completely flatten the vertices along the X axis. If the vertices you have selected had some variations along the Z axis, you could instead use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> instead of <kbd>X</kbd> to scale on all axes but the Y, so that they would be perfectly flat. Confirm the scale operation, and then, with all of the vertices still selected, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select remove doubles. This will merge together any vertices that are in the exact same position.

One other thing I should mention is that blender has a feature called *Auto merge editing* that will automatically merge vertices that are in the exact same place. This could be used to save a step in method two. The feature can be found at the bottom of the 3D view on the right side of the toolbar there. It is the little button with the two arrows pointing to the center.

Method two sounds longer when I describe it here, but in practce, once you become familiar with the shortcuts it is quicker that way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is some sort of "*Merging vertices only along x-axes*" or in other words "*Merge vertices with identical x-coordinate*".

Two ways to accomplish this come to my mind:

**Option 1:** [Merge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merging-vertices) the front and back vertices separately

1. Select the front eight vertices
2. Merge "At Center" with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
3. Select the back eight vertices
4. Merge "At Center" with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

**Option 2:** [Scale to zero only in X-direction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/basics.html?highlight=scale#operator-panel) and [remove doubles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles)

1. Select all bottom vertices/faces.
2. Press <kbd>s</kbd> for scale,
3. while scaling press <kbd>x</kbd> to only scale along X-axis (X-Constraint),
4. and <kbd>0</kbd> to set scale factor to zero.
5. Confirm scale with <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Finally "Remove Doubles" in selection (via Toolbar-Button or search with <kbd>Space</kbd>)

Comment: Aah didn't refresh to see the other answer!